# using "ps" to find processes in a time range

Tags: linux, bash, ps

How can I find started processed within last 5 hours? Can `ps` do that?

I have to use `ps -ef | grep <username>` which shows all process for . Then I have to manually look at STIME columns

Answer (score 2):

`ps -eo etime,pid` will list all PIDs together with the elapsed time since the process creation in the format `[[DD-]hh:]mm:ss`. This may come in handy as you can then search for time amounts less than 5:00:00 instead of performing trickier date comparisons.

Comment: +1 for the simple way. But as I wanted a solution that work for any amount of days and is sortable... well, see below (far, far below ^^) for my take on it (using only things available on ancient, really ancient systems... and that works on aix & solaris, for all I know)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps you:

> do a ps -aef. this will show you the time at which the process
>   started. Then using the date command find the current time. Calculate
>   the difference between the two to find the age of the process.

credit goes to: [How do you kill all Linux processes that are older than a certain age?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134/how-do-you-find-the-age-of-a-long-running-linux-process)

Answer (score 1):

`stat -t /proc/<pid> | awk '{print $14}'`

will give you the start time of a process in seconds since the epoch. Compare with current time (`date +%s`) to find the age of a process in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the laughs, here is what I had to do on some ancient systems (both aix and solaris), and it seems just about "ok" up to now... (but may fail when something changes in the future. Also, I think it already fails on machines where processes last for more than 999 days... I'll fix this when I find one)

On those ancient systems:

- some options of ps don't exist. (or differ between solaris & aix, or different versions of those).
- Some defunct process have either no time, or have also no username, nor pty, nor time.
- ps have a little shift for etime having days>99

The little thing below takes care of those cases (and more) ... but is really ugly ^^

---

Edit: New version (a bit saner, and versatile, but still show you need to process ps output **a lot** to get something usable... thanks to it having a weird way of changing the number of information it displays...)

```
max_size_var_awk="399" #old awk (and nawk) limit of a var size ?!
ps_output_prettifier="%10s %8s %8s %3s %-14s %11s %10s %s\n" #11s for /dev/pts, as it could also be "zoneconsole" in a solaris zone...
truncated_mark="(...)"
size_to_truncate=$(( ${max_size_var_awk} - ${#truncated_mark} ))
tmpfile=

#get the ps output
  ssh localhost "ps -elo user,pid,ppid,nice,etime,tty,time,args" \
   | awk '(NF==5) { $8=$5;$7=$4;$6="-";$5="000-00:00:0-";$4=$3;$3=$2;$2=$1;$1="-"; }
                  { print $0}' \
   | sed -e 's/^  *//' >"${tmpfile:-/tmp/defaulttmp.$$}"


  #we read the ps output, putting the first few items in their respective var, and the rest (cmd + args) in "_rest"
  while read _u _p _pp _n _e _tt _ti _rest ; do

    #special case: we just read the first line:
    [ "$_ti" = "TIME" ] && {
      printf "${ps_output_prettifier}" "$_u" "$_p" "$_pp" "$_n" "99999__$_e" "$_tt" "$_ti" "$_rest"
      continue
    }

    #for all the other lines:
    </dev/null nawk -v u="$_u" -v p="$_p" -v pp="$_pp" -v n="$_n" -v e="$_e" -v tt="$_tt" -v ti="$_ti" -v template="00000-00:00:00"  \
        -v rest="$(printf "%s" "$_rest" | cut -c 1-${size_to_truncate})" -v lrest="${#_rest}" -v trunc="${truncated_mark}" -v totrunc="${size_to_truncate}"  \
        -v ps_output_prettifier="${ps_output_prettifier}" '
           BEGIN { rem="we add the beginning of the template to the beginning of the etime column..."
                   prefix=substr(template,1,length(template)-length(e)) ; e=prefix e;
                   rem="and add the message IF it was truncated"
                   if (lrest>totrunc) { rest=rest trunc ; }
                   rem="modify -hh:mm:ss into .hhmmss to allow sort -n to operate on all (and not just on nb-of-days)"
                   sub(/-/,".",e) ; sub(/:/,"",e) ; sub(/:/,"",e)

                   printf (ps_output_prettifier,u,p,pp,n,e,tt,ti,rest);}'
  done <"${tmpfile:-/tmp/defaulttmp.$$}" \
    | sed -e 's/^/ /' | sort -k5,5nr \
    | sed -e 's/ \([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)/ \1-\2:\3:/'
```

---

Old version:

The convoluted sed (like the last one) try to keep the alignement (and the output is more aligned than what ps does). (I would use awk if I could, but as changing anything on $1, $2, ... or $0 recomputes the whole line, I can't easily keep the alignement. maybe I should just do simple things and process it all via a simpler printf to realign?.... I will do that sometime later! (but I fear that long args lines may mess things up... And I don't know how to tell printf "just format the first few args, and put everything else as-is in the last %s")

Adding back-in the regular ps 'time' would be quite some work, as it have 1 or 2 columns whether the process is dated of more or less than 24h, and the spacing would become all wrong again, and the last sed would fail, etc.

```
LC_ALL=C
ps -eo user,pid,ppid,nice,etime,tty,time,args \
 | sed   -e 's/^\( *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*\)  \([0-9]-\)/\1 00\2/'                \
         -e 's/^\( *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*\) \([0-9][0-9]-\)/\1 0\2/'             \
         -e 's/^\( *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*\)    \([0-9][0-9]:\)/\1 000-\2/'       \
         -e 's/^\( *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*\)       \([0-9][0-9]:\)/\1 000-00:\2/' \
         -e 's/^\( *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*\)           -/\1 0?_-__:__:__/'        \
 | sed -e 's/^/ /' | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\)-/\1./' | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\):/\1\2/'        \
 | sed -e 's/NI     ELAPSED/NI 999._ELAPSED/'                                                            \
 | sort -k5,5nr                                                                                          \
 | sed -e 's/\( [0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\) /\1-\2:\3:\4 /'            \
 | sed -e 's/^  *\([^ ][^ ]*\)\(  *\)\([^ ][^ ]*\)\(  *\)\([^ ][^ ]*\)\(  *\)\([^ ][^ ]*\)\(  *\)\([^ ][^ ]*\)$/ ________ \1 \3 \5 0?_-__:__:__      -    \7 \9/'
```

Enjoy ^^ [and it is still a work-in-progress... works so far, but I couldn't try it on other systems (linux? other versions of aix & solaris, etc)]