# Kill all R processes that hang for longer than a minute

Tags: r, bash, ubuntu, kill

I use crontask to regularly run Rscript. Unfortunately, I need to do this on a small instance of aws and the process may hang, building more and more processes on top of each other until the whole system is lagging.

I would like to write a crontask to kill all R processes lasting longer than one minute.  [I found another answer on Stack Overflow that I've adapted that I think would solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134/how-do-you-kill-all-linux-processes-that-are-older-than-a-certain-age). I came up with;

```
if [[ "$(uname)" = "Linux" ]];then killall --older-than 1m "/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --file=/home/ubuntu/script.R";fi
```

I copied the task directly from htop, but it does not work as I expect. I get the `No such file or directory` error but I've checked it a few times.

I need to kill all R processes that have lasted longer than a minute. How can I do this?

Comment: I suspect you need "pkill" rather than "killall". http://superuser.com/questions/220517/how-to-kill-a-process-with-name-having-spaces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to avoid killing processes from another user and try *SIGKILL* (`kill -9`) after *SIGTERM* (`kill -15`). Here is a script you could execute every minute with a *CRON job*:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROCESS="R"
MAXTIME=`date -d '00:01:00' +'%s'`

function killpids()
{
    PIDS=`pgrep -u "${USER}" -x "${PROCESS}"`

    # Loop over all matching PIDs
    for pid in ${PIDS}; do
        # Retrieve duration of the process
        TIME=`ps -o time:1= -p "${pid}" |
              egrep -o "[0-9]{0,2}:?[0-9]{0,2}:[0-9]{2}$"`

        # Convert TIME to timestamp
        TTIME=`date -d "${TIME}" +'%s'`

        # Check if the process should be killed
        if [ "${TTIME}" -gt "${MAXTIME}" ]; then
            kill ${1} "${pid}"
        fi
    done
}

# Leave a chance to kill processes properly (SIGTERM)
killpids "-15"
sleep 5

# Now kill remaining processes (SIGKILL)
killpids "-9"
```

Comment: A few comments: `$USER` should already by a usable shell variable. piping `pgrep`  to a plain `xargs` is redundant. You can save a bit on processing `ps` output if you use the correct options: `ps -o time:1= -p ${pid}` will give you just the time for that PID.

Comment: Will this not select all processes that have `R` in their name?

Comment: @MiserableVariable the `-x` option of `pgrep` should be used, I guess.

Comment: Yes it would be safer. Edited.

Answer (score 8):

Why imply an additional process every minute with cron?
Would it not be easier to start R with [timeout from coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html), the processes will then be killed automatically after the time you chose.

```
timeout [option] duration command [arg]…
```

Comment: so it would look like: ```timeout --kill-after=1m Rscript /home/ubuntu/script.R```

Comment: Almost, here it worked with:  

     timeout 60 Rscript /home/ubuntu/script.R
Alternatively, you can test with
     time timeout 60 Rscript /home/ubuntu/script.R

Answer (score 5):

**I think the best option** is to do this with `R` itself. I am no expert, but it seems the `future` package will allow executing a function in a separate `thread`. You could run the actual task in a separate thread, and in the main thread sleep for 60 seconds and then `stop()`.

---

*Previous Update*
user1747036's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35244710/18573) which recommends `timeout` is a better alternative.

---

*My original answer*

This question is more appropriate for superuser, but here are a few things wrong with

```
if [[ "$(uname)" = "Linux" ]];then 
  killall --older-than 1m \
    "/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --file=/home/ubuntu/script.R";
fi
```

- The `name` argument is either the name of image or path to it. You have included parameters to it as well
- If `-s signal` is not specified `killall` sends `SIGTERM` which your process may ignore. Are you able to kill a long running script with this on the command line? You may need `SIGKILL` / `-9`

More at http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall