# How to kill certain process running more than 36 hours and containing certain phrasse in its command?

Tags: linux, kill, kill-process

on the Linux (CentOS 6), i want to kill process containing "pkgacc" in its command (so no exact command but just partial match) if it is running more than 36 hours.

There is related question: [How do you kill all Linux processes that are older than a certain age?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134/how-do-you-kill-all-linux-processes-that-are-older-than-a-certain-age/) but any of the solutions provided do not work for me.

when executing:

```
 if [[ "$(uname)" = "Linux" ]];then killall --older-than 1h someprocessname;fi
```

It just return killall usage page on how to use killall, in its manual page there is no mention about "--older-than" switch.

Comment: This seems to be related and may help: http://serverfault.com/a/166044

Answer (score 1):

It is infinitely easier to invoke a program in a wrapper like `timeout` from [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) than to go hunting for them after the fact. In particular because `timeout` owns its process, there is no ambiguity that it kills the right process. Thus

```
timeout 36h pkgaccess --pkg_option --another_option package_name
```

where I made up the names and options for the pkgaccess command since you didn't give them. This process will run no longer than 36 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like

```
ps -eo pid,cmd,etime
```

then you could parse the output with grep searching for you process, 
something like that:

```
ps -eo pid,cmd,etime | grep pkgacc
```

you will have some output with one or more result, the last column from the output must be the time of running process, so one more little bash effort
and you could check if the time is greater than 36 hours.

```
#!/bin/bash

FOO=$(ps -eo pid,cmd,etime | grep -m 1 pkgacc | awk '{ print $1" "$3 }'| sed -e 's/\://g')
IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$FOO"
if [ "${array[1]}" -gt "360000" ]; then
    echo "kill the process: ${array[0]}"
else 
    echo "process was not found or time less than 36 hours"
fi
```

I think that could solve part of your problem,
see that I do not explicit kill the process but just indicate
what it is. You could improve the idea from that.